# Problems with "rake test"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have one problem with the command "rake test" that I don't know how to resolve. When I execute this command show me:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: primary_key_name is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2 (use foreign_key instead). (called from foreign_key at /home/guilhermec/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@iba-jornais/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/active_record/matchers/association_matcher.rb:194)
```

What can I do to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning stems from a deprecated method in a gem. If you want you can:

- file a issue on the [project page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)
- fork the gem and replace the method
- ignore it

edit: this seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/9) in shoulda-matchers since 9 months